# Detect focuslost with many subcomponents

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, focus

I want to create an expandable panel (to accomodate several UI elements for specific tasks). The panel can be expanded by user action, and should stay expanded as long as any subcomponent in the panel has focus. When the user puts focus somewhere outside the panel, then it should close.

Is there an easy way

- either to get a focuslost event when focus moves out of any subcomponents
- or to query whether any subcomponent of the panel still has focus?

Or would I need to register/check for focus(-events) on every subcomponent?
(Since this should be a generically usable panel, I need a generic approach which is independent from the specific hierarchy of subcomponents.)

Comment: My guess is that you would have to monitor the focus of every Swing component in the JFrame, both inside and outside the expanding JPanel.  Otherwise, how would you know that the focus is on a component outside of the expanding JPanel?  I'd do this monitoring on a per JPanel basis. The JPanel getChildren method should prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommended way of grouping focus listeners on multiple `Component`s, according to [the official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#trackingFocus), is to install a single `PropertyChangeListener` on the current `KeyboardFocusManager`. For example something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        
        final int rows = 5, cols = 5;
        final JPanel focusables = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, cols, 10, 10));
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
                focusables.add(new JTextField("Focusable", 10));
        
        final JPanel nonFocusable = new JPanel(); //FlowLayout.
        nonFocusable.add(new JTextField("Click here to change focus"));
         
        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contents.add(focusables, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contents.add(nonFocusable, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                final Object newValue = evt.getNewValue();
                if (newValue instanceof Component
                        && SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom((Component) newValue, focusables)) //If 'focusables' is a parent of newValue...
                    focusables.setBackground(Color.GREEN); //Then focus is back on our components...
                else
                    focusables.setBackground(Color.RED); //Else the focus is not on our components (it may even be another application).
            }
        });
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multi focus lost");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

According to the tutorial:

> The property change listener is notified of every change involving the focus...

How to use the above example:

1. Run it, and you can click in each `JTextField` to give it focus.
2. If the currently focused `JTextField` has for its parent a `Component` that we specify (which is the parent `JPanel` of the desired `JTextField`s in this case, named `focusables`) then the background color of that parent changes to green, otherwise red. But you can obviously implement your logic instead of changing the background color.

How the above example works:

1. We install a `PropertyChangeListener` on the current `KeyboardFocusManager` for the property `focusOwner`, which will let us get notified only when any `Component` in the application changes its focus-owner property (ie changing the focused `Component` triggers such an event). We can install a `PropertyChangeListener` such that we get notified for all sorts of events, but the `focusOwner` is what we are only intersted in, so we let the system know. For a list of all properties you can track by focus events, scroll to the [bottom of the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#properties).
2. Inside the `PropertyChangeListener` implementation we only need to check that the new focus owner has the `focusables` panel for its parent. We can check this by traversing the `Component` hierarchy upwards from the focus owner, or just call `SwingUtilities#isDescendingFrom` which is a convenience method for this purpose. If we were listening to all the focus events, then we would also have to filter manually the property `focusOwner` (by checking that `PropertyChangeEvent#getPropertyName` returns it).

Note that the focus from our desired `Component`s is lost when we are leaving the application (but gets back when we return).

Also note that the hierarchy of `Component`s in the above example is only one level deep for simplicity (ie the desired focusable `Component`s are direct children of the `focusables` panel), but we can change this to any level deep we want, as long as the desired `Component`s all have the same parent along their path (which has to be different from the parent of the non-desired ones).

---

The only exception that I can think of is if you generally have mixed parent `Container`s, ie `JPanel`s for example that have as direct children both a desired `Component` and a non-desired one. In this case, you will have to check for each `Component` individually in the `PorpertyChangeListener` or implement a `FocusListener` for each desired `Component`. The official tutorial on how to implement a `FocusListener` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html).

Comment: In case you want to go with the `FocusListener` option, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very elegant way of approaching it! Yes, my desired components are all within one parent, so this fits nicely. Thanks for the good example code!